# I want to remove some pics from my Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I want to remove some pics from my Excel spreadsheet,but they are quite a few and some I need to keep... Is there a fast way to leave the pictures I want and delete the ones I dont want?

Comment: Btw I can't use the GoTo function as it will remove all of them

Comment: How could a computer tell which you do or do not want to be deleted?

Comment: That's why I am asking for help... Excel may have some function, either VBA or normal, which allows me to browse the pictures I want to delete, and not all of them

Comment: If you're not going to post anything helpful just don't post.
Even a "There's no way possible" would been more helpful than what you are saying

Comment: Alright, let me elaborate. A computer cannot look at a picture the way you can. So, you have to _specify_ on what things the computer has to select pictures, the file name for example. I don't think there is some kind of tool for this.

Comment: Couldn't you say that at the start? Way more helpful, besides Im new in excel so spare me a little...

Comment: It was a question I thought you would understand. Maybe your answer would be: "well, in every filename of a picture that needs to be deleted it has a number." And then we could help you further. but never mind.

Comment: If it did I would be able to solve it myself ... Thanks anyways

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78791/discussion-between-moffeltje-and-daniel-santos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Excel which pictures to **keep**, so in column **A**, list the name of the pictures you wish to keep.  Then run this small macro:

```
Sub PicturePerfect()
   Dim s As Shape, N As Long, i As Long
   Dim Keep As Boolean
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Keep = False

   For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      sn = s.Name
      Keep = False
      For i = 1 To N
         If sn = Cells(i, "A").Value Then
            Keep = True
         Exit For
         End If
      Next i
      If Not Keep Then
         s.Delete
      End If
   Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: The thing is, I dont have the picture's name, they were already on the file and have been previously deleted :/

Comment: It worked, saved the pic and renamed it and it worked thanks again

Comment: If you click on a picture in a worksheet, its **Name** will be displayed in the *Name Box* (which is just to the left of the *Formula Bar*)